# Multicoin wallets with programmable API

Tags: wallet, api, development

Does there really not exist a web multicoin wallet that has a programmable API that can be used by apps to send transactions? It is common practice to authorize your credit card in an app so that it can make transactions without explicitly asking for it each time, but I can't find any way to do this with cryptocurrencies.

I think blockchain.info wallet allows this, but it is Bitcoin only. Any ideas?